# installing netbeans says no compatible Java found

Tags: java

what do I need to install, the SDK?

my program files folder has a java/jre6 installed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need the JDK. You can get it [here](http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/widget/jdk6.jsp).

You could also have downloaded [NetBeans and the JDK together](http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/widget/jdk_netbeans.jsp).

Comment: I like the bundle myself I keep it archived on a thumb drive just in case I need to set up on a new/strange computer.

Answer (score 4):

Just install the JDK or the JDK + NetBeans Bundle, the JRE isn't enough to compile java. Don't worry its all free [here](http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/index.jsp)

Comment: Sorry too much dealing with paying for VS lately.

Answer (score 1):

If memory serves me you need the JDK.  [JDK 6 Update 17 Download](http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/widget/jdk6.jsp)